# JQuery Ajax Not Sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am doing

```
var title = $("#newcourse_title").val();
var description = $("#newcourse_description").val();
var link = $("#newcourse_link").val();
var image = $("#newcourse_imagelink").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/courses/addcourse/",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        link: link,
        img_link: image
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

but my expressjs application dosent even receive the request, that makes me think that it is a problem with the ajax. It dosent give any errors either. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="newpost_form">
<form id="new_course_form">
    <input type="text" id="newcourse_title">


    <textarea id="newcourse_description"></textarea>

    <input type="text" id="newcourse_link">

    <input type="text" id="newcourse_imagelink">



    <input type="submit" class="button newpost_submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: your button type is submit maybe you can chage it to button and bind action to that button

Comment: you ajax call doesn't have a error callback and thats why maybe ur not getting an error message. and i suppose you want the ajax call to happen `onsubmit` of the form

Comment: Show the full context of how you initiate the request. Also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: `dataType: "json",` says the response will be json.  So the service **must** return valid json, even if it's just `{}`.  If it does not return valid json, the request may be successful with a 200 response code, but jQuery will get an error when trying to convert it to an object for you which will make it go into the error callback rather than the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax `dataType` is json and I think you should serialize the postData to Json. You can use `JSON.stringify`;

```
var title = $("#newcourse_title").val();
var description = $("#newcourse_description").val();
var link = $("#newcourse_link").val();
var image = $("#newcourse_imagelink").val();
var postData = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        link: link,
        img_link: image
    };
$.ajax({
    url: "/courses/addcourse/",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways but I guess this will work

```
 function trigger(){

    var title = $("#newcourse_title").val();
    var description = $("#newcourse_description").val();
    var link = $("#newcourse_link").val();
    var image = $("#newcourse_imagelink").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/courses/addcourse/",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            link: link,
            img_link: image
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

    }
 <input type="button" onclick="trigger()" class="button newpost_submit" value="Submit">


$("form").on("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    trigger();
})

<input type="submit" class="button newpost_submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: you can bind form action to submit and prevent default so you can call ajax also. There are several ways